# How to Make Universe Factory More Popular

Tags: discussion, blog

The question is simple:  What techniques or strategies must I need to support and publicize the [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory) blog site?

Comment: When this gets answers I'm stealing them for [The Retrocomputing Blog](//retrocomputingblog.wordpress.com).

Comment: What is your eventual goal?

Comment: Advertise more on World Building. This site gives you free access to your target audience. Also link relevant blog posts to relevant questions and maybe have a meta post listing blog posts so people who don't follow the blog closely can see if a new article has come up that they may be interested in reading.

Comment: You should add the link to it in your question. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @wannabeLearner  Here's my whole dollar--I don't think Stack Exchange will allow advertising links.

Comment: That's not completely true, links to relevant content (such as Universe Factory) are not classed as adverts and are allowed so long as used appropriately. In addition we already use the "community ad" system they provide to publicize the blog.

Comment: @JohnWDailey And here it would really be relevant, i think at least