# How can I become writer in Universe Factory blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I just came to know about the Universe Factory blog when I read [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/how-to-make-universe-factory-more-popular?cb=1) question on meta. Professionally I am a software developer but I love to write and scribble. Is there any way to apply for becoming writer in Universe Factory?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for making occasional contributions; it also links to the post where you can apply to become a regular contributor, so it covers both cases.

Comment: Note: I removed the [support] tag because the blog technically has *nothing* to do with Worldbuilding SE; it just happens to be populated by a subset (and likely also a superset) of the people here.

Comment: Thanks. but that question should be edited as someone like me who wants to become a regular writer could not even care to open and see whether there is answer for my requirement also.

Comment: You don't have the reputation to edit on Meta, but by all means feel free to comment on the question to suggest that improvement if you feel it is needed (but do note that we also have that other question about becoming a regular contributor).

Comment: Just a very brief answer: come to the [dedicated chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory) and say hi. The rest will follow from there :).

Comment: We'd love to have you! Please sign up on Medium if you haven't already and ping bilbo in the chat room to get added as a writer. You can also chat with folks about topics and such. (I can usually help out too but my network access is very limited right now, which is why I'm redirecting you instead of directly helping. Sorry.)